# Access model primary key dynamically based on fieldtype

Tags: coldfusion

I am dumping the following component.

Instead of doing `Object.getUserID()` manually each time, I want to get the primary key of the model dynamically based on property with `fieldtype="id"`. Can anyone help on this?
https://cfdocs.org/cfproperty#p-fieldtype

This is how I declare my property:

`<cfproperty name="UserID" fieldtype = "id"  type="numeric"/>`

`getMetaData(Myobject).properties;` gives me the array of structure.

[image]

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: To help you understand what I am implementing, I have written a function `getObjector404(Object,id);` which is being called in my controllers. It accepts the object and the ID. So This function has to get the primary key of the object dynamically to make some checks. I have written a function in every model, `getPK()` which already does that but I want to eliminate that process. So I believe it's better to just add `fieldtype = "id"` on the property instead of writing `getPK()` function in every model. It may be more resourceful but definitely cleaner code in models

Comment: This looks a lot like `EntityLoadByPK("NameOfTable", id)`. Is ORM an option?

Comment: No, we do not use ORM. We use custom SQL in the models. Each model is a component with properties and standard functions, e.g. read update, create, delete, save

Comment: So what happens when you tried to access the value by using `getMetaData(Myobject).properties[arrayindex].fieldtype` ?